# How to give page animation effect in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a project based on ionic framework. I want to give 'slide up' and 'slide down' page transition effects. Is there any way of doing this. I have tried using ngAnimate but it doesn't work for me. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please show the source code you have tried sofar and copy exact error messages here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this package in your project:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-transitions

Comment: I have used it but it doesn't work for me at all

Comment: My bad, I missed to install "cordova plugin add com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions" now its working for me.  thanks @rldona